# Drupal on IIS - Cannot connect to the database

Tags: php, iis, drupal, drupal-6

I've hard time to make Drupal work on IIS Microsoft server. I've succesfully run Joomla on the same server so I'm pretty sure the following information are correct:

```
host: localhost
user: user
pass: pass
databaseName = servername_databasename
```

I've set the following line in settings.php file:

```
$db_url = 'mysql://user:password@localhost/servername_databasename';
```

but what I get is this:

```
If you are the maintainer of this site, please check your database settings in the settings.php file and ensure that your hosting provider's database server is running. For more help, see the handbook, or contact your hosting provider.
```

I don't get any other error message such as: database doesn't exist, user/pass wrong.. just this.

The database is running, I can access with phpmyadmin.

I've tried both "mysql" and "mysqli". The host is a private server (IIS Microsoft), the database is Mysql

The database and website files upload have also been succesfull.. so I dunno what to do to fix this issue.

thanks

Comment: Is `settings.php` file readable by the webserver?

Comment: i have some issues to change file permissions from my ftp client since it is not apache server. I cannot even see them... do you know how can I solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried giving the full server name in place of localhost?  It might make a difference.

Comment: you mean this ? $db_url = 'mysql://user:password@www.servername.com/servername_databasename';

Comment: I've tried to replace localhost with "www.servername.com" "http://www.servername.com" and "servername.com" .. still nothing, exactly same page.

Comment: Have you tried turning `error_reporting` to it's highest available value (`E_ALL | E_STRICT`)?  This may require finding where it's set in the source and editing that file.  You may also need to `ini_set('display_errors', true)`

Comment: well, I cannot change server settings I guess (I even cannot change permissions, since it is Microsoft). And about ini_set, I'm using the default Drupal CMS, so I guess everything I don't have to add any php code. It usually informs me about different errors (such as wrong pass, or wrong database name), but in this case it only says it cannot connect to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved... it was just wrong dataset setup.